# How to add attachment to a Email that uses API method to send Email

Tags: c#, api, email, c#-4.0, authenticator

I am creating a Even attachment that looks like this .

```
    string schLocation = "Conference Room";
    string schSubject = "Business visit discussion";
    string schDescription = "Schedule description";
    System.DateTime schBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime("7/3/2008 10:00:00 PM");
    System.DateTime schEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("7/3/2008 11:00:00 PM");

    //PUTTING THE MEETING DETAILS INTO AN ARRAY OF STRING

    String[] contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
                          "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",
                          "BEGIN:VEVENT",
                          "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                          "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                          "LOCATION:" + schLocation,
                     "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,
                          "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3",
                     "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR" };

    /*THE METHOD 'WriteAllLines' CREATES A FILE IN THE SPECIFIED PATH WITH 
   THE SPECIFIED NAME,WRITES THE ARRAY OF CONTENTS INTO THE FILE AND CLOSES THE
    FILE.SUPPOSE THE FILE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE SPECIFIED LOCATION,THE CONTENTS 
   IN THE FILE ARE OVERWRITTEN*/

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Sample.ics"), contents);

    //METHOD TO SEND EMAIL IS CALLED
    //  SendMail();
    //System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("Sample.ics"));
```

}

Now i want to Send the Attachment via Email using not smtp but API method like `HttpBasicAuthenticator` How do i send Attachment in this method in smtp its a library `Attachment` what is used in API ?

Comment: `System.Net.Mail` will send via the configured server details but the protocol is effectively stuck at SMTP using those objects as far as I'm aware. If you need to send the email via HTTP, then it's completely down to the API implementation as to how that's done

Comment: Oh so the attachment is strictly for only system.net.mail huh  ok wait i will put in my code for ending the email how i send it via API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer 
when send the Email via API you use

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient();
```

and then use this line of code to have a attachment

```
request.AddFile("attachment", path);
```

and it looks like this

[image: This is how you can download your attachment that you send]

source Link [Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending)